# ng-switch not working even isactive is false

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-switch

There are two buttons in ng-switch, if isActive is false, either one should show, but it is showing both buttons.what wrong i am doing?

```
<div ng-switch="user.IsActive">
  <div ng-switch-when="false">
  <button type="button" (click)="activateDeactivateUser(user.UserId,user.IsActive)" class="btn btn-primary active">Deactivate</button>
    </div>
```

Activate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to be using an ngSwitch here, but rather an ngIf:

```
<div *ngIf="user.IsActive">
  <button type="button" (click)="activateDeactivateUser(user.UserId,user.IsActive)" class="btn btn-primary active">Deactivate</button>
</div>
```

When the user.IsActive variable returns true, the button will display.  When it returns false, the button will be hidden.

On a separate note, your syntax for the ngSwitch is incorrect.  The proper syntax follows this pattern:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="variableCondition">
    <component1 *ngSwitchCase="variableCondition1"></component1>
    <component2 *ngSwitchCase="variableCondition2"></component2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using ng-if for booleans.

```html
<div>
  <div ng-if="user.IsActive">
    <button type="button" (click)="activateDeactivateUser(user.UserId,user.IsActive)" class="btn btn-primary active">Deactivate</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-if="!user.IsActive">
    <button type="button" (click)="activateDeactivateUser(user.UserId, user.IsActive)" class="btn btn-primary active">Activate</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

But this is an example for ng-switch

```html
<div ng-switch="user.IsActive">
  <div ng-switch-when="true'">
    <button type="button" (click)="activateDeactivateUser(user.UserId,user.IsActive)" class="btn btn-primary active">Deactivate</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when="false">
    <button type="button" (click)="activateDeactivateUser(user.UserId, user.IsActive)" class="btn btn-primary active">Activate</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post the JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Angular ng-switch will evaluate your `false` as variable not as **`boolean`** `value` so change your switch case as `ng-switch-when="'false'"`

> **example**

```
<div ng-switch="user.IsActive">
                                                    <div ng-switch-when="'false'">
                                                        <button type="button" (click)="activateDeactivateUser(user.UserId,user.IsActive)" class="btn btn-primary active">Deactivate</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div ng-switch-default>                                                                
                                                        <button type="button" (click)="activateDeactivateUser(user.UserId,user.IsActive)" class="btn btn-primary active">Activate</button>
                                                    </div>
                                            </div>
```